# apply vector in double square brackets in R

Tags: r, list, lapply, data-retrieval

is there anyway to apply vector to [[]] in R

e.g. b is a list

```
b <- list(16,'dsdfs',35)
a <- c(1:3), b[[a]]
```

it doesn't work, and I know [[]] and $ only accept single values, [] accept vectors, but b[a] is a list of list, which is not what I want.

is there anyway to solve this problem, since it is really annoying, that I couldn't dare to use `lapply`. just because it returns list of lists of lists, which, except for using [[]] or $ I don't have other ways to go into the atom element. But [[]] and $ is not easy to do loop.

like python, you can always go further with [] e.g. list[3][2][3]...

Does R have the same thing?

Thank you.

Comment: maybe `unlist(b[a])` is what you want?

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: I suspect that replacing the comma in `a <- c(1:3), b[[a]]` with a semicolon and using "[" rather than "[" will fix everything. It is going to deliver a list.

Comment: And do read the help page for "[" and "[[" where it is explicitly emphasized that "[[" can only take an argument that results in a single value. It can take an argument with multiple elements if the structure being accessed permits.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns Thank you for your suggestion, for the real situation I cannot use it, because unlist will unlist all the list, including lists in list, which in fact, I just want to unlist the most outside list, and keep all the inside lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example is so far syntactically erroneous. I'm assuming you meant to write:

```
a <- c(1:3); b[[a]]
#Error in b[[a]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2
```

If your intent was to return all three elements of the 'a'-list then you simply cannot use "[[" unless you wrap it in some loopy function. If you used `sapply` you would get a character vector.

```
  sapply(a, function(x) b[[x]])
 [1] "16"    "dsdfs" "35"
```

Which may be your goal.

To illustrate how one might pass a multiple element vector to "[[" and not have it throw an error, look at this:

```
> b2 <- list(16,list('test','dsdfs'),35)
> a <- c(1:3); b2[[c(2,1)]]
[1] "test"
```

The vector: c(2,1) is being expanded by "[[" to be the same call as:

```
 b2[[2]][[1]]
```

The `b2[[2]]` returns `list('test','dsdfs')` and then the `[[1]]` is applied to that result and returns the atomic vector `'test'`. That is what the error message earlier was calling "recursive indexing", but in this case the process was able to find a single list element to return because all of the indices that were successively/recursively supplied to "[[" were able to deliver a list-item value.

Comment: just to make it up to you, I liked your reply here

Comment: I wonder if just `unlist(b[a])` will do instead of the `sapply` loop

Comment: @Nemo: I was writing up an answer your match.fun error pointing to R-FAQ 7.30 when I got the popup saying the question had been deleted. You still might get benefit from running down the list of items in section 7.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: Surely. I was just trying to adhere to the request to use "[[".

Comment: @BondedDust  Thank you very much, it do help me a lot!  Then I can just use [[c(a,b,..)]] to go into lists.